# Can't get rid of NuGet official package source

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I go into the Package Manager -> Package Sources options and remove the NuGet official package source so that only my local source is available. Then I close visual studio 2010. As soon as I re-open Visual Studio, the NuGet official package source is still at the top of Available Package Sources. https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=206669

I have tried exporting and importing settings, deleting relevant suo files to no avail. This happens even when I don't open a solution.

One thing that I have found is that when I open VS the second time, the following config file is correct. C:\Documents and Settings{myusername}\Application Data\NuGet\NuGet.Config

As soon as I open the Package Manager under Tools -> Options, the official source gets added to NuGet.Config so,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="Local Package Source" 
        value="http://nuget:8081/DataServices/Packages.svc/" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration
```

Is changed to...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <!-- new line below -->
    <add key="NuGet official package source" 
        value="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=206669" />
    <add key="Local Package Source" 
        value="http://nuget:8081/DataServices/Packages.svc/" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration
```

This file doesn't get changed when the Options dialog opens, just when I click on the Package Manager in the Options tree view.

Where is it getting this setting from and why does it keep inserting it?

**Update copied from Ben Phegan on same issue on CodePlex**

http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1696

"I think this might be an issue with the implementation of AddOfficialPackageSourceIfNeeded() here"...
http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/2b36b2e1935a#src%2fVisualStudio%2fPackageSource%2fVSPackageSourceProvider.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some code within the NuGet vsix itself that adds the default feed back if there are no others in the list, but it appears that there is a bug in it:

```
    if (officialFeed == null)
    {
        // There is no official feed currently registered

        // Don't register our feed unless the list is empty (other than the aggregate). This is the first-run scenario.
        // It also applies if user deletes all their feeds, in which case bringing back the official feed makes sense.
        if (_packageSources.Count > 1)
        {
            return;
        }

    }
```

This then falls through and adds the official feed as the first source.  I would add another source so that you have >1 source (a local directory should work).  This should prevent this behaviour.

The Nuget.exe command has similar behaviour, however it is added by default regardless of the sources available.

I believe this behaviour does differ by version.  What version are you using?

Comment: Thanks Ben. I will check this out. I am using version 1.5.20902.9026

Comment: Ben, Whereabouts in the vsix package is that code? Did you reflect/peek into one of the dlls?

Comment: You can find the code at http://nuget.codeplex.com - so I didnt really do anything special!  :)

Comment: Thanks Ben. I have taken the liberty to copy the exptra info from your CodePlex answer into an Update to my question.